# How can I build a dynamic CGEventFlags in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I have several keyboard shortcuts that my app is using and I would like to dynamically build the correct CGEventFlags for each shortcut. I know there are questions that describe how to do this with a static event, but I would like to run dynamic CGEvents and I'm having trouble elegantly creating the correct value. I'll also be honest, bit masks don't make much sense to me. Is there any way to convert this to the dynamically get the correct CGEventFlag? Here's what I've been trying to do without success:

```
let shortcut = "control shift option command L"

var flags = [CGEventFlags]()

if shortcut.contains("control ") { flags.append(.maskControl) }
if shortcut.contains("shift ")   { flags.append(.maskShift) }
if shortcut.contains("option ")  { flags.append(.maskAlternate) }
if shortcut.contains("command ") { flags.append(.maskCommand) }              


let mask = flags.someConversionFunction()...
```

Comment: `CGEventFlags` is an *OptionSet*. A single `CGEventFlags` value represents a set of 0 or more options (CoreGraphics event flags, in this case). You should use a single value, and not an array of them. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGEventFlags` conforms to [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset), which means that you can use *set* operations on it (as `OptionSet` inherits from `SetAlgebra`) and not worry about bit operations at all.

So basically, think of a variable of type `CGEventFlags` as a *set* of flags. For example, you can `insert` and `remove` flags from it, as well as forming `union`s and `intersection`s with other `CGEventFlags`.

```
var flags: CGEventFlags = []

if shortcut.contains("control ") { flags.insert(.maskControl) }
if shortcut.contains("shift ")   { flags.insert(.maskShift) }
if shortcut.contains("option ")  { flags.insert(.maskAlternate) }
if shortcut.contains("command ") { flags.insert(.maskCommand) }  

// now you can assign "flags" to CGEvent.flags
```

If you do have a `[CGEventFlags]` and want to convert to a single `CGEventFlags`, just use the `init(_:)` initialiser - this is the same initialiser as the one you use to convert `[Int]` to a `Set<Int>`. It's a bit counterintuitive, but `CGEventFlags` is a *set of* `CGEventFlags`.

Here I rewrote your code to be less imperative (without the mutable `var`), as an example of converting from `[CGEventFlags]` to `CGEventFlags`:

```
let shortcut = "control shift option command L"
let eventFlagDictionary: [_: CGEventFlags] = [
    "control": .maskControl,
    "shift": .maskShift,
    "option": .maskAlternate,
    "command": .maskCommand
]
let flags = CGEventFlags(
    // the below is a [CGEventFlags]
    shortcut.split(separator: " ")
        .compactMap { eventFlagDictionary[String($0)] }
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew this had to be possible, and even simpler than I supposed! Also, your explanation is FAR better than anything else I've found on the topic...which isn't much, by the way. I also learned from your answer an interesting way to use dictionaries!